# Sharepoint file does not update with Python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, sharepoint, openpyxl

I wrote a Python script that will update an Excel file (using openpyxl module) on Sharepoint. I can read the file and manipulate data using xlrd module, but it seems like it's just not saving the information that I'm trying to save. Here's the sample code that I wrote:

```
workbook = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename="\\\\server\\location\\file.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.get_active_sheet()

    for i in range(0,13):
        valuetoAdd = infoList[i]
        worksheet.cell(row=numRows+1,column=i).value=valuetoAdd
    workbook.save("\\\\server\\location\\file.xlsx")
```

Any suggestions on why this isn't working? The file location works for xlrd module (therefore I don't connect to Sharepoint online with login credentials). Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error do you get? We've had a report that suggests that Sharepoint creates files we have trouble reading. (https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/issue/304/cannot-read-all-worksheet-one-is-missing) so I wonder if this is related.

Comment: There aren't any error messages. I also don't think it's a related issue -- I'm having trouble saving after I modify the fie, not reading the data in.

Comment: No error messages at all? So a file is created but just not where you need it? Could be a network issue. Maybe you can mount the remote server as a local drive? Tip: you can use Python's r"" strings to make the paths easier: `pth = r"\\server\location\file"` But basically we don't do anything special when saving the file. The difference with xlrd being that xlsx files are actually zip files. Don't think that should matter.

Comment: I'm not actually creating the file, I'm trying to append some data to already existing file. The purpose of my program is to make changes to the file via Python code so that everyone can view the same file on the sharepoint at any given time. *Thanks for the tip!

Comment: If you save the file locally is it as you expect? I'm asking because we improved support for Sharepoint generated files at the weekend and there's a possibility that the file was being saved back but being ignored by Sharepoint. This is still a possibility as we don't process the custom stuff written by Sharepoint.

Comment: Yup it looks like it works with a local copy of the spreadsheet. I'm guessing it just doesn't work with Sharepoint :/

Comment: You can probably manually add all the custom some stuff that we dispose of to see if that works. To do that download the file from Sharepoint and unzip it. After editing the file in openpyxl save it locally under a different name and unzip it. You can compare the differences using the Office Open XML SDK 2.5 and can probably make the changes manually to the new archive. Zip it and try saving it on your Sharepoint server. If it works then that will help us add the functionality in the future.

Comment: The problem with that would be that all of our sharepoint documents require check out; there's really no point of using python script if I will have to download/upload each time. We want to implement automatic checkout/checkin process with the script so whenever someone's running the code, no one else can make any changes.. But uploading a file on sharepoint does work.

Comment: Well, if the problem is related to additional stuff written by Sharepoint then it might be possible to get openpyxl to use it so that check out and chek in would work. Not having Sharepoint anywhere I can't really test this.

Comment: Ok now I got the script to upload the file, but it remains checked out after I save the workbook. Is there a way to check it in as well?

Comment: I suspect it maybe possible with the metadata. I suggest you carry on the discussion either as a feature request for Openpyxl or on the mailing list. I don't have access to Sharepoint or your files so can't really say.